# automatically insertion database with counter reset within a day

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL Server table like this

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id |  account  |    date    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|    |  John     |  2016/6/2  | 
|    |  John     |  2016/6/2  | 
|    |  John     |  2016/6/2  | 
|    |  John     |  2016/6/4  | 
|    |  Andi     |  2016/6/4  | 
|    |  Steve    |  2016/6/2  | 
+----+-----------+------------+
```

the problem is i want to insert automatically the "id" column by the date, and change the date into string like datatype(char/varchar) AND ADD increment 3 digit counter at the end (start from 001) that reset the counter every day (reset when the date is change but may continue by the last counter if the date is same). 
example :

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+
|     id      | account |    date   |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 20160602001 | John    |  2016/6/2 | 
| 20160602002 | John    |  2016/6/2 | 
| 20160604003 | John    |  2016/6/2 | 
| 20160604001 | John    |  2016/6/4 | >counter reset when the date is change
| 20160604002 | Andi    |  2016/6/4 | 
| 20160604004 | Steve   |  2016/6/2 | >counter continue 
+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

I want to make it in oracle sql developer can someone help me a bit?
i've been thinking to try this in pure database query is it possible? (it's okay to add more column or modify a bit as long the "id" column stay remain like i need) or is it need to make a function in C# (ASP.NET) to do this? because this is the one i understand quite well, can someone help me solve this? thankyou =)

Comment: You have a SQL Server table and you want to do something on it in Oracle SQL Developer? How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create separate columns for the date and the id. When inserting row just get the max id from that day, and if it doesn't exist, start from 1. You can create an additional computed column for the date + id field if you really need it, but in the table you should keep them separated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Oracle:

If your table exists already, with the columns you show, and you want to populate the column ID, you can do that with an UPDATE statement as below. I used the table name "t" - you need to change it to your actual table name everywhere it appears in my query. I also call the date column dt (it is always a bad idea to use Oracle key words as table or column names); if your column is really called "date" you will have to replace dt with "date" (including the double quotes).

```
update t set id = 
    (with h(dt,rn) as 
        (select dt, row_number() over (partition by trunc(dt) order by dt) from t)
     select to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') || to_char(rn, 'FM009') from h where h.dt = t.dt)
```

This assumes the "date" column is truly a date column, with a time component, and no "dates" are equal (the time component for the same day is different for all records). Otherwise the select statement returns more than one row and the insert will fail. In that case you need to explain how you want to break the ties; the insert statement will be a little more complicated.